# How to use getDeclaredConstructor if my constructor accepts a primitive type?

Tags: java

I am finding a constructor like this:

```
type.getDeclaredConstructor(Integer.class);
```

This works when type is

```
MyType {
public MyType(Integer a);
}
```

However, this does not work when type is

```
MyType {
public MyType(int a);
}
```

And I do not want to replace `int` with `Integer` as I was told it may incur unnecessary overhead.

What do I do?

Comment: Regarding having been told that you might occur in unnecessary overhead, that's not really true and that's not likely to impact your application performances. The overhead you have been told about is the boxing/unboxing of integers which is even optimized for integers withing -128, +127

Comment: @Raffaele Rossi Ain't boxing/unboxing going to happen if I have MyClass(Integer i) and do new MyClass(2) ?

Comment: if you invoked new MyClass(2) on MyClass(Integer i) then boxing wouldn't happen as in your JVM there should be a cached Integer object corresponding to 2 (might depends on JVM implementations though)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
type.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class);
```

From [section 15.8.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2):

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a '.' and the token class.

Comment: For some reason, this is one of the lesser known secrets of Java.